# preg_replace replace only the string between two symbols if it contains something specific

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to only replace string between two symbols and start replacing just if the string contains specific word for example:

```
$string = '%Test% %font-style:italic; font-weight:bold;%'; //It Can be with different orders such as
$string = '%Test% %font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;%';
```

So The string which I want to use preg_replace for is the string between this two symbols `%%` and I want to use preg_replace just if the string contains one of css tags such as `font-style:italic; color:red; font-weight:bold; etc..` I've tried

```
$string = preg_replace('`\%(.*?)((.*?):(.*?);)(.*?)\%`si', '(span style="$2$5")', $string); // ( used as start tag html symbol
```

But It caused a problem when I used it for

```
http://localhost/NaiTreNo/Games/Games/BatMan%20Arkham%20Knight/Image/Cover.jpg :D %color:blue; font-weight:bold;%
```

it should return:

```
http://localhost/NaiTreNo/Games/Games/BatMan%20Arkham%20Knight/Image/Cover.jpg :D
<span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;">
```

But it returned:

```
http://localhost/NaiTreNo/Games/Games/BatMan<span style="20Arkham%20Knight/Image/Cover.jpg :D %color:blue; font-weight:bold;%">
```

Please help.

Comment: Have a try with [`%([^\d%][^%]*?:[^%]*;\s*)%`](https://regex101.com/r/wO6vL0/2) and replace by `<span style="$1">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `regex` is too loose. It only checks for the presence of `:` and `;` somewhere inside the string. I would use the knowledge that CSS property names have a specific format to make a `regex` rule that won't match any string that contains `:` and `;`.

For example, something like this:

```
#%(([a-z]+(-[a-z]+){0,2}: *[^;]+;)+)(.*?)%#si
```

A [`CSS` property name](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html) starts with a word containing one or more lowercase letters `[a-z]+`, followed by zero, one or two more words, each of them preceded by a dash `(-[a-z]+){0,2}`.

A rule to restrict the too-accepting `.*?` used for values can also be created but the outcome doesn't pay the effort (and the `regex` becomes difficult to understand.

How the `regex` works:

```
%                      # your custom boundary start symbol
  (                    # start of group #1 used to capture the CSS rules
    (                  # start of group #2 that captures a single CSS rul
      [a-z]+           # first word of CSS property name
      (-[a-z]+){0,2}   # 0-2 more words, separated with dash (-)
      : *              # the colon followed by optional white spaces
      [^;]+;           # anything until the first semicolon (at least one character)
    )+                 # end of group #2; it can repeat; at least one occurence is required
  )                    # end of group #1
  (.*?)                # captures everything after the last semicolon
%                      # your custom boundary end symbol
```

The `regex` above doesn't match when there is only one CSS property and its value is not followed by a semicolon, f.e. `%color: red%`. In order to fix this, the `+` symbol after group #2 must be replaced with `*` (to match zero or more CSS rules ended with `;`) but this way the ending `(.*?)` will match anything, including `Test` or the URL in your examples.

This can be fixed by replacing `.*?` in the last group with the content of group #2 without the ending `;`. The expression becomes longer and more difficult to understand and I won't post it here. You better make sure your CSS rules always end with a semicolon (`;`), including the last one.

A playground for this `regex` can be found at: https://regex101.com/r/vC1oS2/3

Answer (score 0):

I can propose to add a space at the beginning.

```
$string = preg_replace('`(^| )\%(.*?)((.*?):(.*?);)(.*?)\%`si', ' <span style="$2$5">', $string); // ( used as start tag html symbol
```

Try at https://3v4l.org/uubF7

Comment: `%font-style:italic;% http://localhost/NaiTreNo/Games/Games/BatMan%20Arkham%20Knight/Image/Cover.jpg :D %color:blue; font-weight:bold;%` it won't replace `%font-style:italic;% ` :( so your code can't replace if the string was at the begging.

Comment: Updated. But it's not ideal solution. Better use BB codes or something similar.

Comment: tried that before but it returned `<span style="italic"> http://localhost/NaiTreNo/Games/Games/BatMan%20Arkham%20Knight/Image/Cover.jpg :D <span style="blue"></span></span>`

Comment: What do you actually need? Where those `</span>` are from? There is no any `</span>` in your question's example.

Comment: Actually it's for comment system and </span> generates automatically in the end of the string.

Comment: Can you show what you expect from your example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35727980/preg-replace-replace-only-the-string-between-two-symbols-if-it-contains-somethin/35728092?noredirect=1#comment59131262_35728092 ?

Comment: I expect from `%font-style:italic;% http://localhost/NaiTreNo/Games/Games/BatMan%20Arkham%20Knight/Image/Cover.jpg :D %color:blue; font-weight:bold;%` => `<span style="font-style:italic;"> http://localhost/NaiTreNo/Games/Games/BatMan%20Arkham%20Knight/Image/Cover.jpg :D <span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold;"> `

Comment: My code produces exactly this result. Click the link and look at output.